# "Super" key shortcut to Activities with second keyboard layout

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I have the following problem with the new Ubuntu 20.04 LTS when adding a second keyboard layout.

Everything works fine when using the layout selected during installation. Once I add a secondary layout, and begin to use it, the Super shortcut to Activities doesn't work anymore.

Moreover, if I go back to the first layout it works again. If I change the order of the layouts, the shortcut only works with the first layout. It doesn't seem to be dependent on the layout itself.

Is someone able to reproduce the same issue?

Comment: I should add that every configuration is on default, as it's a brand new installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a gnome bug affecting multiple distros. Here, for example, a bug report for fedora:

[Can't activate "Activites overview" with secundary keyboard layout](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1822354)

And the thread in gitlab

[super no longer opens overview (with dvorak keyboard layout)](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1144)

This all happens under X11. Temporary solution is to change to Wayland if possible.